# Configure Adblock to filter web pages in Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, adblock

There's an ad the [Adblock extension for Google Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/adblock-%E2%80%94-best-ad-blocker/gighmmpiobklfepjocnamgkkbiglidom?hl=en) fails to remove. Adblock Plus didn't work any better.

It looks like just removing the following line in the HTML page would do the trick, but since it's HTTPS, Privoxy won't work.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://static.criteo.net/js/ld/publishertag.js" ></script>
```

Does someone know how to configure Adblock to edit HTML on the fly?

Thank you.

Comment: I have always used uBlock Origin, far better at stopping all sorts of webpage nonsense.

Comment: Thanks. It seems to have done the job for that particular banner. I'll see if it can be used to rewrite HTML on the fly à la Privoxy.